# AMX Authorization Header in Postman

Tags: authentication, http, postman

I have an endpoint i'm trying to reach using Postman but it uses an amx authorization header.
Is there anyway I can use Postman to generate an amx authentication header value?

This is all I can find on what an amx authentication header is.

https://developer.allscripts.com/content/fhir/content/amx_auth_header/index.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried creating a header variable called amx and pasting the generated token into that value (I have a C# application that generates the token for me).

I also tried to create a header variable called "Authentication" and use "amx  ....." as the value.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate an amx authentication header value". Should the header be generated automatically in Postman or do you want to set this header with the token manually?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Pre-request Script to set the amx token to a variable and then use it in your request:

> To include code you want to execute before Postman sends a request, do the following:
>
> 1. Select Collections in the sidebar.
> 2. Open the request, then select the Pre-request Script tab.
> 3. Enter the JavaScript you need to process before the request runs, then select Save.
> 4. Select Send to send the request. The code will execute before Postman sends the request to the API.

source: https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/#scripting-before-your-request-runs.

If you have the generation already in C#, you will need to translate it into Javascript. As far as I know, there is no utility to generate it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).